# What to do with Grandad's Top Secret documents

Tags: united-states, military, probate, secret

He worked for the US government and left behind some documents that might be actually important. What's the proper procedure here, do we destroy everything or is there somewhere we should take these?

Comment: Do you mean the documents are literally marked "Top Secret?"  If so, don't they list an agency or office?  Where were they "left?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documents do not belong to you or your granddad: they belong to his former employer. Contact them and ask what *they* want them do with them.

Comment: This definitely seems like the correct answer, the Dept. of Energy can't seem to direct me to someone who knows/cares however.

Comment: @JohnJones put them in an envelope with a explanatory note and post it to them.